# passport.js and process.nextTick in strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm facing something new in nodeJS: `process.nextTick`

In some strategies code examples for passport.js, we can see

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {

    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {

      findByUsername(username, function (err, user) {
        // ...
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
          // ...
        });
      })
    });
  }
));
```

But in the official documentation, it is not used. (http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/)

What I understand is that `process.nextTick` should be used to defer synchronous stack to not block an event. But in this strategy code, there is no event.

What the benefit of doing that here ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's only there in the example to show that async authentication is possible.  In most cases, you'd be querying a database, so it'd be async in nature.  However, the example just has a hard-coded set of users, so the `nextTick` call is there for effect, to simulate an async function.

Comment: Perhaps this is something that should be left as a commented out block in sample code? I noticed you had the nextTick in the passport-twitter example code as well. I appreciate the reason to simulate an async function, however, I haven't found ANY blog sample code where they don't use nextTick (and it seems to be unneeded).

Comment: so If we just take out `process.nextTick(function () {` and the closing `}`. the parent function (passport middleware) will still work to query DBs?

Answer (score 0):

100% ES6 working so you can delete the nextTick
I use babel and webpack at server side to so:

import passport from 'passport';

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

const manipulateUser = async (User, profile, done, token) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
    if (user) {
      user.accessToken = token;
      await user.save();
      return done(null, user);
    }
    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.googleId = profile.id;
    newUser.name = profile.displayName;
    newUser.avatar = profile.photos[0].value;
    newUser.accessToken = token;
    profile.emails.forEach((email) => { newUser.emails.push(email.value); });
    await newUser.save();
    return done(null, newUser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err at manipulateUser passport', err);
    return done(err);
  }
};

const strategy = (User, config) => new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: config.googleAuth.clientID,
  clientSecret: config.googleAuth.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.googleAuth.callbackURL,
}, async (token, refreshToken, profile, done) => manipulateUser(User, profile, done, token));

export const setup = (User, config) => {
  passport.use(strategy(User, config));
};
```