# Can't understand use of delay in server side code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a code for a simple nodejs application which allows users to login and signup their accounts. Here is a part of the code used for signup process:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, 
function(req, email, password, done){       
    // asynchronous
    // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
    process.nextTick(function(){

        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user){               
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);
             // check to see if theres already a user with that email
             if(user)
             {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
             }
             else
             {
                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUser = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.local.email = email;
                newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
             }

        });
    });
}));
```

Here they have used `process.nextTick()` to kind of delay the execution of the `function()` and the comment says: `User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back`
. Is this comment talking about `data being sent back to client`? And what `data` is this comment talking about? And why do we have to delay its execution? What would be the repercussions if we didn't delay this execution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passport.js and process.nextTick in strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743348/passport-js-and-process-nexttick-in-strategy)

Comment: So in this case it won't matter if I remove `process.nextTick()` call?

Comment: Yes, it can be safely removed.